# Store in sharedPreferences

Tags: android

I have some things in my app that I need to store, in order to have it available the next time I open the application. I wonder if I could save them using the sharedPreferences mechanism even if I don't have any "view" associated with them  ! .If this is possible please let me know, if not, what would you suggest instead ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All you need is a component that can furnish you a handle to the android.os.Context
An Activity is such a component. SharedPreference's data is stored in a file - somewhat akin to a properties file (key,value pair).

You can also create your own files and store it in the app's private directory.

Comment: could you show here through a piece of code how to store an int for example ?